# Capture list from first non-blank value

Tags: excel-formula

I have a named range which captures 1st row to last non-blank row. The formula I use is

```
=OFFSET(DataSheet!$L$1,0,0,COUNTA(DataSheet!$L:$L),1)
```

Now I want to create another named range which would capture values from first non-blank value to last non-blank value in the below scenario

- 
- 
- 
- 
- Person 2
- Person 3
- Person 4

so in above scenario, I want the name range to only contain the person 2 to person 4. In future, if a new Person 1 is added above Person 2, then I want that captured as well.

Thank you for your help!

Did not work:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this by adding a row offset instead of that first zero.

Something like the following

```
=OFFSET(DataSheet!$L$1,
    MATCH(FALSE(),ISBLANK(DataSheet!$L:$L),0)-1,0,
    COUNTA(DataSheet!$L:$L),1)
```

Note that if you have intermediate blank values, then `COUNTA` won't give you the full range to the last nonblank. To fix that you could use the following:

```
=OFFSET(DataSheet!$L$1,
     MIN(IF(ISBLANK(DataSheet!$L:$L),9^99,ROW(DataSheet!$$L:$L)))-1,0,
     MAX(IF(ISBLANK(DataSheet!$L:$L),0,ROW(DataSheet!$L:$L)))-
     MIN(IF(ISBLANK(DataSheet!$L:$L),9^99,ROW(DataSheet!$L:$L)))+1,1)
```

---

If those cells aren't actually blank, then you need a different condition. For example,

```
=OFFSET(DataSheet!$L$1,
     MIN(IF(LEN(DataSheet!$L:$L)<1,9^99,ROW(DataSheet!$$L:$L)))-1,0,
     MAX(IF(LEN(DataSheet!$L:$L)<1,0,ROW(DataSheet!$L:$L)))-
     MIN(IF(LEN(DataSheet!$L:$L)<1,9^99,ROW(DataSheet!$L:$L)))+1,1)
```

Comment: Sorry it did not work. I've added the screencap to my question (see at bottom). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Dingo Can you verify that those rows are truly blank? They may have a space or an empty string or something in them.

Comment: Ow they have formulas (my bad - sorry)

Comment: @Dingo In that case, instead of `ISBLANK`, try `LEN() < 1`.

Comment: That worked like a charm. I've learned something new as well! Thanks!